# Using array_intersect on a multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-intersect

I have two arrays that both look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => STRING
            [value] => STRING
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => STRING
            [value] => STRING
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => STRING
            [value] => STRING
        )
)
```

and I would like to be able to replicate array_intersect by comparing the ID of the sub arrays within the two master arrays.  So far, I haven't been successful in my attempts.  :(

Comment: Doing a custom comparison, you'll need to use `array_uintersect()` http://php.net/array_uintersect, which uses a user-defined comparison function.

Comment: Despite all of the upvotes on this old post, your question does not contain a good, clear [mcve].

Comment: [Compare two 2D arrays & get intersection and differences](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37564953/2943403)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Use [`array_uintersect()`](http://php.net/array_uintersect) to use a custom comparison function, like this:

```
$arr1 = array(
           array('name' => 'asdfjkl;', 'value' => 'foo'),
           array('name' => 'qwerty', 'value' => 'bar'),
           array('name' => 'uiop', 'value' => 'baz'),
        );

$arr2 = array(
           array('name' => 'zxcv', 'value' => 'stuff'),
           array('name' => 'asdfjkl;', 'value' => 'foo'),
           array('name' => '12345', 'value' => 'junk'),
           array('name' => 'uiop', 'value' => 'baz'),
        );

$intersect = array_uintersect($arr1, $arr2, 'compareDeepValue');
print_r($intersect);

function compareDeepValue($val1, $val2)
{
   return strcmp($val1['value'], $val2['value']);
}
```

which yields, as you would hope:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => asdfjkl;
            [value] => foo
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => uiop
            [value] => baz
        )

)
```

Comment: How could you modify this to make sure all columns match, not just 'value'?

Comment: @bafromca I think return strcmp(serialize($val1), serialize($val2)); might work

Comment: better use a recursive funktion like: `function compare_arrays($a, $b) {
    if (is_array($a) && is_array($b)) {
        $diff = array_udiff($a, $b, 'compare_arrays');
        return empty($diff) ? 0 : 1;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}  $result = array_uintersect($a, $b, 'compare_arrays');`

Answer (score 4):

you can use embedded function with array_uintersect php function. ex:

```
$intersectNames = array_uintersect($arr1, $arr2, function ($val1, $val2){
    return strcmp($val1['name'], $val2['name']);
    });

$intersectValues = array_uintersect($arr1, $arr2, function ($val1, $val2){
    return strcmp($val1['value'], $val2['value']);
    });

print_r('namesIntersected' => $intersectNames, 'valuesIntersected' => $intersectValues)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function compareDeepValue($val1, $val2)
{
   return strcmp($val1['value'], $val2['value']);
}
```

Be sure that val2 key is existing in val1 array, because the function is ordering array first. Very strange.