# Array_Intersect not working as expected

Tags: php, arrays, array-intersect

I have two multidemensional arrays and I am trying to use `array_intersect` to find the values from `$array1` that occur in `$array2`. Instead the results, as you can see below, include both values from the first array `$array1` even though only one of the values occurs in the second array `$array2`. I suppose I have some misunderstanding of how this function works, can anyone clarify what I am doing wrong here?

```
var_dump($array1);
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "28"
  }
  [7]=>
  array(1) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "30"
  }
}

var_dump($array2);
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "30"
  }
}


var_dump(array_intersect($array1, $array2));
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "28"
  }
  [7]=>
  array(1) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "30"
  }
}
```

Comment: checkout this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653241/using-array-intersect-on-a-multi-dimensional-array)

Answer (score 0):

The function array_intersect compares the values as strings, see [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php).  Unfortunately, this gives simply "Array" for all arrays.

> ```
> Note: Two elements are considered equal if and only if (string) $elem1 === (string) $elem2. In words: when the string representation
> is the same.
> ```

Instead you can use a custom compare function:

```
array_uintersect($array1, $array2, function($a, $b) { return ($a<$b)?-1:($a==$b)?0:1; })
```

Or use !== if you want to also compare order and types - see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) for the difference.

Answer (score -1):

[array_intersect_assoc()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-assoc.php) looks at key *and* value for intersection.