# Compare two 2d arrays & get intersection and differences

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, filtering, array-difference, array-intersect

I want to compare the data in whole rows between the two arrays and produce:

- an array of intersecting rows and
- an array where rows in the first array are not found in the second array and
- an array where rows in the second array are not found in the first array.

I have two multidimensional arrays with me.

```
$array1 = [
    ['sight_id' => 13, 'location' => 'Jodhpur, Rajasthan, India'],
    ['sight_id' => 14, 'location' => 'Jodhpur Jn, Jodhpur, Rajasthan, India'],
    ['sight_id' => 15, 'location' => 'D-Kirtinagar, Jodhpur, Rajasthan, India'],
];

$array2 = [
    ['sight_id' => 13, 'location' => 'Jodhpur, Rajasthan, India'],
    ['sight_id' => 14, 'location' => 'Jodhpur Jn, Jodhpur, Rajasthan, India'],
    ['sight_id' => 16, 'location' => 'Jaisalmer, Rajasthan, India'],
    ['sight_id' => 17, 'location' => 'Fort Road, Amar Sagar Pol, Jaisalmer, Rajasthan, India'],
];
```

Desired results:

```
$intersect_array = [
    ['sight_id' => 13, 'location' => 'Jodhpur, Rajasthan, India'],
    ['sight_id' => 14, 'location' => 'Jodhpur Jn, Jodhpur, Rajasthan, India'],
```

and

```
$only_a1 = [
    ['sight_id' => 15, 'location' => 'D-Kirtinagar, Jodhpur, Rajasthan, India'],
]
```

and

```
$only_a2 = [
    ['sight_id' => 16, 'location' => 'Jaisalmer, Rajasthan, India'],
    ['sight_id' => 17, 'location' => 'Fort Road, Amar Sagar Pol, Jaisalmer, Rajasthan, India'],
];
```

Comment: For common data array I done this..`function multi_array_intersect($a, $b) {
 return strcmp ( $a ['sight_id'], $b ['sight_id'] );
}
$common_sights = array_uintersect ( $a1, $a2, 'multi_array_intersect' );`

Comment: Edit your question to explain what have you done to try achieving desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert arrays to a format, where array index is the sight_id:

```
$b1 =array();
foreach($a1 as $x)
    $b1[$x['sight_id']] = $x['location'];

$b2 =array();
foreach($a2 as $x)
    $b2[$x['sight_id']] = $x['location'];
```

Calculate the differences and intersection:

```
$c_intersect = array_intersect_key($b1,$b2);
$c_1 = array_diff_key($b1,$b2);
$c_2 = array_diff_key($b2,$b1);
```

Convert arrays back to your format:

```
$intersect_array = array();
foreach($c_intersect as $i=>$v)
    $intersect_array[] = array('sight_id'=>$i,'location'=>$v);

$only_a1 = array();
foreach($c_1 as $i=>$v)
    $only_a1[] = array('sight_id'=>$i,'location'=>$v);

$only_a2 = array();
foreach($c_2 as $i=>$v)
    $only_a2[] = array('sight_id'=>$i,'location'=>$v);
```

Comment: What if in future I have to add two more columns to that array..??

Comment: Then instead of storing just `$x['location']` column, store whole row `$x` . Then restore it simply `$only_a2[] = $v `

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to mutate/prepare your two-dimensional arrays in order to compare the rows.  Because whole rows from one array relate to whole rows in the other array, you don't need to specify a column to compare -- just compare the full row data.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Ndqs1)) ([Or with a declared function](https://3v4l.org/s4a39))

```
echo "Intersection:\n";
var_export(
    array_uintersect($array1, $array2, fn($a, $b) => $a <=> $b)
);

echo "\nUnique in first:\n";
var_export(
    array_udiff($array1, $array2, fn($a, $b) => $a <=> $b)
);

echo "\nUnique in second:\n";
var_export(
    array_udiff($array2, $array1, fn($a, $b) => $a <=> $b)
);
```

Output:

```
Intersection:
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'sight_id' => 13,
    'location' => 'Jodhpur, Rajasthan, India',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'sight_id' => 14,
    'location' => 'Jodhpur Jn, Jodhpur, Rajasthan, India',
  ),
)
Unique in first:
array (
  2 => 
  array (
    'sight_id' => 15,
    'location' => 'D-Kirtinagar, Jodhpur, Rajasthan, India',
  ),
)
Unique in second:
array (
  2 => 
  array (
    'sight_id' => 16,
    'location' => 'Jaisalmer, Rajasthan, India',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'sight_id' => 17,
    'location' => 'Fort Road, Amar Sagar Pol, Jaisalmer, Rajasthan, India',
  ),
)
```