# Comparing 2D-arrays - finding unique items

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have 2 arrays and need to identity the items in array2 that do not occur in array1.

Only the 1st, 2nd and 4th elements should be compared when checking for uniqueness, the 3rd element (amount in stock) should be left out of the comparison.

```
var array1 = [['892','NEW','2','blue'],
     ['675','USED','2','white'],
     ['943','NEW','2','green'],
     ['121','USED','2','yellow']];

var array2 = [['892','NEW','1','blue'],
     ['892','NEW','1','yellow'],
     ['121','USED','1','blue'],
     ['121','NEW','1','blue'],
     ['121','USED','1','yellow']];
```

Result should be:

```
 result = [
     ['892','NEW','1','yellow'],
     ['121','USED','1','blue'],
     ['121','NEW','1','blue']];
```

I've tried reworking several solutions posted to similar questions but haven't been able to work it out for this specific situation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37564953/compare-two-multidimensional-arrays-get-difference-unique-values-in-two-diff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take a hash table and a function which generates a key out of the given array and filter `array2` by checking the hash table.

```js
function getKey(array) {
    return [0, 1, 3]
        .map(function (i) { return array[i]; })
        .join('|');
}

var array1 = [['892', 'NEW', '2', 'blue'], ['675', 'USED', '2', 'white'], ['943', 'NEW', '2', 'green'], ['121', 'USED', '2', 'yellow']],
    array2 = [['892', 'NEW', '1', 'blue'], ['892', 'NEW', '1', 'yellow'], ['121', 'USED', '1', 'blue'], ['121', 'NEW', '1', 'blue'], ['121', 'USED', '1', 'yellow']],
    hash = Object.create(null),
    result = [];

array1.forEach(function (a) {
    hash[getKey(a)] = true;
});

result = array2.filter(function (a) {
    return !hash[getKey(a)];
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**UPDATE 2023**

With a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) as *`thisArg`* for [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```js
const
    array1 = [['892', 'NEW', '2', 'blue'], ['675', 'USED', '2', 'white'], ['943', 'NEW', '2', 'green'], ['121', 'USED', '2', 'yellow']],
    array2 = [['892', 'NEW', '1', 'blue'], ['892', 'NEW', '1', 'yellow'], ['121', 'USED', '1', 'blue'], ['121', 'NEW', '1', 'blue'], ['121', 'USED', '1', 'yellow']],
    getKey = array => [0, 1, 3].map(i => array[i]).join('|'),
    result = array2.filter(
        function (a) { return !this.has(getKey(a)); }, // no arrow for this
        array1.reduce((s, a) => s.add(getKey(a)), new Set)
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I really like this answer, are you happy with this version in ES6? for the function `const getKey = (array,idx) => idx.map(i => array[i]).join('|');` then declare the elements/indexes you want to keep `const el = [0,1,3];` and then to create the hash table `array1.forEach(a => hash[getKey(a,el)] = true);` and get the result `let result = array2.filter(a => !hash[getKey(a,el)]);`

Comment: @TopMarx, please see edit.

Comment: Thank you, very interesting, I found the `forEach(function (a) {hash[getKey(a)] = true;` easier to understand, but that's only because I'm learning. Could you say a little on how the filter is working in the updated answer?

Comment: it uses the second parameter of `filter` to have all in a single method. but the main key is a `Set` in the `reduce` to collect known items. the first parameter of `filter` takes the `Set` as `this` and allows to use it for a check.

Comment: thank you again, and from reading the links, this is why no arrow function: "_The `thisArg` argument is irrelevant for any `callbackFn` defined with an arrow function, as arrow functions don't have their own `this` binding._" I need to learn more about `Set` but it seems well suited to this type of problem: "_A value in the set may only occur once_".

Answer (score 1):

In js it would be something like (changed to shorter code):

```
array2.filter(function(val){
  return !array1.some(function(item){
    return (val[0] == item[0] && val[1] == item[1] && val[3] == item[3]);
  })
});
```

Comment: Could simpliiy this to:  array2.filter(function(val){
   array1.forEach(function(item){
      return val[0] === item[0] && val[1] === item[1] && val[3] === item[3];
}); })

Comment: Except that it doesnt work, those are nested functions man.. ;)
Also, edited the code cause it appears op wanted the exactly opposite version.

Comment: @vicbyte I had already accepted Nina's answer, I like your approach also, which is a bit easier to follow.

Comment: I agree her approach is better for large sets, since it will be just faster. I also got the idea of hashtables, but by that time she already posted the response, so... :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this ... whatever index you want to skip just give it in index[] below code

foreach (var numberA in a)
        {
            foreach (var numberB in b)
            {
                if (numberA == numberB)
                {
                    if (a.inex[3]) { }else
                    lblDate.Text += numberA.ToString();
                }
            }
        }