# get common value from two array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two Array say Array1 and Array2

```
Array1
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => abc

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => xyz

        )
)

Array2
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => abc

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => qwe

        )
)
```

I want to fetch common value from both Array so the FinalArray should be:

```
FinalArray
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => abc

        )

)
```

I tried this :
in_array function
But it returns nothing just a blank array.

Comment: search php manual for array intersection function. do some ground work before raising a question!

Comment: Ok so i want the code you wrote..

Comment: array_intersect is what you're looking for

Comment: go through the link  http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/5653507/5447994

Answer (score 1):

@Aashi simply use array_intersect like below:

```
<?php
    $finalArr = array_intersect(array_column($Array1, "name"), array_column($Array2, "name"));
    print_r($finalArr);
```

Comment: I don't encourage this! Let OP try by his own. It hardly takes 1 minute to post an answer. But you are blocking OP's learning curve

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$intersect = array_uintersect($array1, $array2, 'compareDeepValue');
print_r($intersect);

function compareDeepValue($val1, $val2)
{
   return strcmp($val1['name'], $val2['name']);
}
```

Comment: When you grab an answer, why don't you mention it? Question is already duplicate one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5653507/5447994

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
 $array1 = array("5","26","38","42");

 $array2 = array("15","36","38","42");

 $result = array_intersect($array1, $array2);

 print_r($result);
```