# How to compare attributes

Tags: php, sql, arrays, yii, dao

I have the following code and the output will be in array. How can I find arrays that match between $pesara and $ahli. the condition between it is CURRENT_ID_NO is equal to ic_no

```
$sql = "SELECT CURRENT_ID_NO, NAME, MOBILE_NO FROM pesara";
    $dbCommand = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql);
    $pesara = $dbCommand->queryAll();

$sql2 = "SELECT name, ic_no, ic_type, tel_no, pesara, created_dt, created_by, updated_dt, updated_by FROM ost_ahli";
    $dbCommand2 = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql2);
    $ahli = $dbCommand2->queryAll();

$result = array_intersect($pesara->CURRENT_ID_NO, $ahli->ic_no);
    print_r($result);
```

Sorry for my bad English but I hope someone can help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_uintersect()](http://php.net/array_uintersect) for custom comparison

and also have sample code for that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653241/using-array-intersect-on-a-multi-dimensional-array)