# Select ONLY values in array 1 and exist in array 2

Tags: php

I have two arrays as displayed below and I want to be able to select **ONLY** values in Array 1 and exist in Array 2

This is my first array:

```
<pre>array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["user_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["user_id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["user_id"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    ["user_id"]=>
    string(1) "4"
  }
}
```

This is my second array:

```
<pre>array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["user_id"]=>
    string(1) "5"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["user_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["user_id"]=>
    string(1) "4"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    ["user_id"]=>
    string(1) "4"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(1) {
    ["user_id"]=>
    string(1) "5"
  }
}
```

I hope to find a more elegant way of doing this.

Comment: See `array_intersect` - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oyedele, so there is this PHP Function called array_interesect which will only return values present in the arguments.

[Click for more info](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)

```
<?php
$array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue");
$array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
$result = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
?>
```

And that returns the following:

```
Array
(
    [a] => green
    [0] => red
)
```

**UPDATE:**
For your case you would need to use [`array_uintersect`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-uintersect.php)

Here is the code

```
// Creating your Arrays

$array1 = array(
           array('user_id' => '1'),
           array('user_id' => '2'),
           array('user_id' => '3'),
           array('user_id' => '4'),
        );

$array2 = array(
           array('user_id' => '5'),
           array('user_id' => '1'),
           array('user_id' => '4'),
           array('user_id' => '4'),
           array('user_id' => '5'),
        );

// Preforming comparison

$intersect = array_uintersect($array1, $array2, 'compareDeepValue');
print_r($intersect);

// Custom Comparison Function

function compareDeepValue($val1, $val2)
{
   return strcmp($val1['user_id'], $val2['user_id']);
}
```

And here is the output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 4
        )
```

[Click here for live demo.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b894b99b820b07a8e4ad1071a027df2c63e35d92)

Comment: @OyedeleFemi No Problem, if it helped you please upvote the answer and mark the checkmark. :) Here is a related question by the way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653241/using-array-intersect-on-a-multi-dimensional-array